# Create Dictionary of Dictionary at Run time in python from a data from a file

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic, runtime

How can we create the Below dictionary of dictionary in python at runtime.

Attached code snippet with desired output when data is manually stored in dictionary.

When Input would be taken from InputFile???

**Input File**

> 00
>
> Called 999000
>
> VLR 365444564544
>
> Calling 2756565
>
> 16
>
> reason_code 12
>
> level 4
>
> severity minor

**Script :**

```
Operation = {'00': {'Called': '999000', 'calling': '2756565', 'vlr': '365444564544'},
                    '16': {'reason_code': '12'}
                   }

for op_id, op_info in Operation.items():
    print("\n Operation ID:", op_id)
    
    for key in op_info:
        print(key + ':', op_info[key])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Operation ID: 00

        Called: 999000

        vlr: 365444564544

        calling: 2756565

 Operation ID: 16

             reason_code: 12 
             
             level :4

             severity :minor
```

How can we create the above dictionary of dictionary in python at runtime
When Input would be taken from InputFile???

Comment: Is your input file something you have control on ? In other words, do you create the input file or you get it from a third party ?

Comment: Your input file is not a dictionary.   Is it supposed to be?

Comment: Is the input file a yml file?

Comment: no its a simple text file..

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the lines with just keys can be detected by counting the words in them, and then the key may be used until there is a new key. Here's an example implementation:

```
def file2dict(file_name):
  with open(file_name) as f:
    res = dict()                 # result
    key = ""                     # we keep the key until there is a new one
    for line in f.readlines():
      words = line.split()       # get words in lines
      if (words):                # check if the line was not empty
        if (len(words) == 1):    # if the length is one, we know this is a new key 
          key = words[0]         # and we change the key in use
          res[key] = dict()      # and create a dict element 
        else:
          res[key][words[0]] = words[1]  # and add key-value pairs in each line
return res
```

Test it:

```
print(file2dict("in.txt")) # your example file
```

Output:

```
{'00': {'Called': '999000', 'VLR': '365444564544', 'Calling': '2756565'}, '16': {'reason_code': '12', 'level': '4', 'severity': 'minor'}}
```